# Export whole Qlik report with Qlik extension

Tags: javascript, qlikview, qliksense

im working on a Qlik extension inside the Qlik extension editor. My goal is to export the current report as pdf and excel. 
I tryed to select the html code, format it and save as pdf first. This worked well since i noticed that just the displayed rows are exportet. It seems like unvisible rows are removed from the html. 
Is there any way to get the data of the report direct? I would build the tables on my own.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data, parsing the hypercube of that report, and then paint it yourself.

This will involve:
       Access the hypercube in your extension.
       Get hypercube's dimensions and measures.
       Loop throught the data painting in on the paint function.

In the initial JS you can define how much the hypercube you want to initially fetch:

```
        initialProperties: {
            qHyperCubeDef: {
                qDimensions: [],
                qMeasures: [],
                qInitialDataFetch: [{
                        qWidth: 24,
                        qHeight: 400
                    }]
            }
        },
```

Then in your code you can parse the hypercube and use its contents to paint the tables (just a proof of concept), overloading the paint function:

```
 paint: function ($element, layout) {
            var lastrow = 0;
            var numDimensions = self.backendApi.getDimensionInfos().length;
            var numMeasures = self.backendApi.getMeasureInfos().length;         
            // This will be your table header
            for (var i = 0; i < self.backendApi.getDimensionInfos().length; i++) {
                html += self.backendApi.getDimensionInfos()[i].qFallbackTitle;
            }
            self.backendApi.getMeasureInfos().forEach(function (cell) {
                html += cell.qFallbackTitle';
            });
            // this will be your table rows
            this.backendApi.eachDataRow(function (rownum, row) {
                   lastrow = rownum;
                   for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
                        if (row[i].qIsOtherCell) {
                            row[i].qText = self.backendApi.getDimensionInfos()[i].othersLabel;
                        }
                        if( row[i].qText !== undefined ){
                            output_string = row[i].qText;
                        }
                        html += output_string ;
                    }
            }
            $element.html(html);
            // there may be more data after that initial fecth
           // request more data until hypercube data ends                      
            if (this.backendApi.getRowCount() > lastrow + 1) {
                var requestPage = [{
                        qTop: lastrow + 1,
                        qLeft: 0,
                        qWidth: 24,
                        qHeight: Math.min(500, this.backendApi.getRowCount() - lastrow)
                    }];
                self.backendApi.getData(requestPage).then(function () {
                    self.paint($element);
                });
            }
        }
```

Actually the important part is, **you  can access the data by loading the hypercube used to build that report**.

Investigate that and you will be done.

Hope this helps.